# jQuery 1.7 parsererror in previously (1.6.3) successful AJAX calls?

Tags: ajax, jquery, webkit, parse-error

I recently swapped out jQuery 1.6.3 for jQuery 1.7 just to see what would happen. My code had been thoroughly tested and was working as expected.

The only problem I'm seeing is nearly all of my AJAX calls, made with jQuery.ajax, are being rejected.

Here's one example:

```
$('button:contains(Commit)',self.$node).click(function(){
    jQuery.ajaxSetup({
        username: self.user,
        password: self.password,
        headers: self.baseHeaders
    });

    console.log(self.URLs.upload);
    $.ajax({ url: self.URLs.upload, type: 'POST' })
     .done(function(){…})
     .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus){…
        console.error(textStatus);
        console.error(jqXHR);
     });
});
```

The call always fails, with textStatus set to "parsererror". The jqXHR has these properties:

- readyState: 4
- responseText: ""
- status: 204
- statusText: "No Content"

So I don't see what the problem is. Does anyone know?

Why would there be a parsererror on a 204 No Content anyway?

Comment: Are you with the `[webkit]` tag implying that this occurs in Webkit based browsers only and thus *not* in all other browsers (Gecko, MSIE, etc)?

Comment: I don't know what this code is doing in other browsers, only webkit-based browsers. This may fail the same way in other browsers, but that remains to be seen.

Comment: What is it that you expect `self` to be?  It's not set in that code anywhere.

Comment: Sorry, that's an alias for the object this code belongs to. I'd use `this`, but jQuery changes the scope of `this`.